# Brunch issue trying to bundle socket.io-client

Tags: socket.io, babeljs, brunch

I have some trouble to bundle socket.io with Brunch/Babel.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  [...]
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^5.8.0",
    "classnames": "2.2.3",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "socket.io-client": "1.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.5.2",
    "brunch": "^2.4.2",
    "css-brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "4.1.0",
    "fb-flo": "^0.5.0",
    "fb-flo-brunch": "^1.7.22",
    "javascript-brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "rangen": "0.3.0",
    "redux-devtools": "3.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "1.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "1.0.4",
    "sass-brunch": "2.0.0"
  },
  [...]
}
```

now my brunch config :

```
exports.config =
  files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo:
        'js/vendor.js': /^node_modules\//
        'js/app.js': /^app\//
    stylesheets:
      joinTo:
        'css/vendor.css': /^node_modules\//
        'css/app.css': /^app\//

  server:
    run: yes

  plugins:
    babel:
      presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
    fbFlo:
      enable: true

  modules:
    nameCleaner:
      (path) ->
        # remove app/js from all
        newPath = path.replace(/^app\/js\//, '')

        # if components or containers we remove component and the last file name
        if newPath.match(/^components\//, '')
          newPath = newPath.replace(/^components\/.*\//, '')
        if newPath.match(/^containers\//, '')
          newPath = newPath.replace(/^containers\//, '')

        return newPath
    autoRequire:
      'js/app.js': ['app']
```

and now my error :

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "engine.io-parser/keys" from "engine.io-parser" 
@ vendor.js:61
```

if I replace in my vendor.js "require('./keys.js')" by "require('./lib/keys.js')" that works ...
Where is my problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Brunch contrib here. Thanks for your report! In general, it's better to report these on our GitHub Issues.

What you are experiencing looks like an issue indeed and I've submitted a PR to address that https://github.com/brunch/brunch/pull/1217